# How to cast a String to char[] in Dart

Tags: arrays, flutter, dart

How to convert a String to an array of char in Dart ?

I've tried to cast a String to a List of char and it didn't work

Comment: kindly, use the search option before writing duplicate questions !

Comment: Dart doesn't have a `char` type.  There is no such thing as a `List<char>`.  You can use [`codeUnits`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/String/codeUnits.html) to get a list of UTF-16 code units, [`runes`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/String/runes.html) to get a list of Unicode code points, or [`package:characters`](https://pub.dev/packages/characters) to get a list of grapheme clusters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through the string, and assign each character to the end of a `List`. Please mark my answer as accepted. Code is given below:

```dart
void main() {
  String str = 'This is a string.';
  List charStr = [];
  
  for(var i=0; i<str.length; i++ ) {
    charStr.add(str[i]);
  }
  
  print(charStr);
}
```